# How to check the progress of an npm installation?

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

I am starting an angular project with `ng new app-name`, and it's been stuck for about two hours here:

[image]

I know it's probably because of my bad internet connection. However, I want a way to check if it is actually progressing, or if it is stuck and I should stop the whole thing.

I am not very good with networks. I am on windows. Is there a way to check the progress of such a thing? (if it's still downloading, etc).

Many thanks.

Comment: I just checked it after I finished typing the question, and I got an error: socket timeout. The installation stopped. Yey. Of course, answers are still welcome as I might need to refer back to them in the future.

Comment: you might want to install a real time Real Time Data Usage monitor ..here is few of them ...https://techviral.net/monitor-real-time-data-usage-windows/

Comment: You could try adding the `--verbose` / `-v` flag to the command to see if increased verbosity provides a better picture.